# Azure Functions Live Metrics shows high number of servers online

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Whenever I start my Azure Functions app, Live Metrics Streaming in Application Insights shows that there are a high number of servers online -- currently sitting at 24 and climbing -- and seems to bring another server online every few seconds or so. This is before I even make a call to any HttpTriggers. And for every call I make to an HttpTrigger, Functions seems to bring another server online (at least that's what Application Insights is saying).

I'm at a complete loss of how to account for this behavior, especially since my app isn't doing anything yet (no requests). There aren't any logged errors that I can see except for the "Unable to acquire Singleton lock" one for new servers, which I'd expect. The CPU% for a server spikes when it comes online, but then goes back down to 0% within a few seconds and stays there.

Even more bizarre is that when I left the app running over night, I saw 180 servers online in the morning and calls to my API were very slow.

Is the "servers online" metric in Live Metrics Stream misleading with Azure Functions, or is there any way to find out *why* there are so many servers being brought online? Does anyone have any other suggestions for how to figure out what's happening?

Comment: I've worked around this for now by deleting my function app and re-creating it with an app service plan instead of a consumption Plan. I have no idea what's different about my app -- it's not very exotic at all -- that is causing issues, but it isn't behaving correctly with a consumption plan. That'll end up costing me more, which is a bummer, but it at least works now.

Comment: Do you have other Functions in this Function App that may be triggering, and thus causing your Function App instances to scale?

Comment: I have a couple of TimerTriggers with RunOnStartup = true. The CPU does spike momentarily while my app is initializing EF models, but 99% of the time those functions have no work to do, and so the CPU goes back down to 0% within a couple of seconds. The behavior I see in App Insights is a couple of seconds of CPU spike due to initialization, several seconds of 0% CPU when it's done, then Functions brings another server online. This happens repeatedly. It seems to me that startup initialization is normal for any app, so maybe Functions should ignore that when trying to decide to scale?

Comment: Michael, in Consumption Plan, the scaling algorithm is only listening on the trigger endpoints and will scale based on the backlog of messages/events. We need to figure out which trigger is causing your Function App to scaled out to that many instances. Kindly open an issue at our GitHub repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues and share your Function App’s info indirectly per instructions here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately. Let me know when you have done so and I will investigate. Thanks!